# LLVM filecheck can not be found

Tags: compiler-errors, llvm

I just try to compile llvm11，but when i used cmake，I found it note that “Failed to find LLVM FileCheck
-- Version: 0.0.0”
and I found the llvm didn't compile and get the filecheck‘s executable file. So how can i fix it？

Comment: Do you mean that your system does not have LLVM FileCheck installed or that the compilation did not build LLVM FileCheck?

Comment: It's an error when configuring with CMake.